# What do you call a div that slides out from beneath another div when moused over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a Javascript effect I'm sure I've seen done many times before. However, I can't seem to find the right terminology for it. It's not a "slider", or a "slide out menu" or a "slide out tab" or a "tab". So far those terms have caused Google to take me to all sorts of examples and tutorials for things that are not what I'm after.

The effect I'm after is like this:

[image: div slide effect]

Div 2 sits behind Div 1 until the user mouses over the visible portion of Div 2, which causes it to slide out to reveal more of itself. When the user mouses away, Div 2 slides back underneath Div 1.

What do you call this effect, so that I can find turorials or Javascript code for it? Or if anyone can direct me to an example or explain how to do it, that would be great.

Comment: In jQuery Mobile there's something similar that is called "Panel". It's not exactly the same, but it might help you to find what you are looking for.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/light/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for a terrible code, but do you need something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/D7Z8v/

```
$("#smalldiv").hover(function() {
$("#smalldiv").animate({marginLeft: 200});       
}, function() {
$("#smalldiv").animate({marginLeft: 0});
});
```

You probably need to change "marginLeft" inside hover function on something more appropriate, but it's looks like what you needed.

Comment: As a note for anyone who uses similar code to this, the top div needs to be set to either "absolute" or "relative". In the JSFiddle example in this answer, "absolute" was used for both divs, but in my page that caused some breakage in my layout. Fortunately, using "relative" positioning for the "bigdiv" and "absolute" for the smalldiv worked just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to have div1 above div2 and then you can either use a [CSS animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), [jQuery animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to change the position of div2 or you can adjust the width of div2.